# How to cache an HTTP response indefinitely

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, caching

How do I send an HTTP response that any client would cache forever (or until its cache is cleared), such that when the browser needs that resource, it makes no HTTP request and instead retrieves the HTTP response from the local file system?

Usage note: this is for versioned client code in an Ajax application. Everything is accessed through the uncacheable example.com/front.htm, which merely contains a script tag linking to example.com/*currentversion*/bootstrap.js which is cached indefinitely. Because the uncacheable HTML file determines the current version, there is no need for the client to update scripts.

Comment: I think the resources are automatically cached unless you add the nocache php header to your responses. About the .js files, this is the same thing, they are cached automatically, you have to change the name to download them again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the RFC, "to mark a response as 'never expires,' an origin server sends an Expires date approximately one year from the time the response is sent. HTTP/1.1 servers SHOULD NOT send Expires dates more than one year in the future."

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21.

I don't know what the reasoning behind the one-year limitation is, so take it for what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Cache until 2038.  You can't go any farther than that (reliably) because of the [32-bit Unix Epoch bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  Use this header:

```
Expires: Sun, 17 Jan 2038 19:14:07 GMT
```